# Can't select multiple cells in Jupyterlab notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I cannot select multiple (adjacent) cells (in order to e.g. delete them)

I have tried

- Shift +up/down arrows
- Shift + J/K
- Both of the above in both Edit mode and Command mode
- Running a javascript keyboard tester to make sure shift J/K not being intercepted
- Windows on-screen keyboard for shift +up/down/J/K
- Online searching for same symptoms

**Question**: any ideas why this is happening and how to resolve it *or* how to perform a more detailed investigation/diagnosis?

Environment: Windows-10 Home 64-bit 20H2; Jupyterlab 3.0.5; Python 3.8.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Dec 26 2020, 04:30:06) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]; IPython 7.18.1

Browsers tested Chrome, Opera, Edge (Chrome has security extensions, all disabled/allowing localhost, but Edge is vanilla and behaved exactly the same)

Starting jupyterlab from Anaconda Navigator launcher

Comment: you might also have some plugins in your browsers that won't let your jupyter-lab take the action.

Comment: @l.mome Edge has no plugins - that was my test case for plug-in dependency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with selection per se, as all selection actions failed (e.g. select all cells from menu), but rather with the display

The CSS value for var(--jp-notebook-multiselected-color) was #e3f2fd - invisibly faint on my monitor; it was declared in the index.css file as "md-blue-50" (Google's Material Design blue) but the colour displayed did not match an online sample of md-blue-50 (so I guess the value for md-blue-50 declared elsewhere was not found).

The issue was identified by switching to to dark mode, where selection highlighting was clearly present.

Solution (because I can't find the source of the md-blue-50 value) was simply to use Stylebot to override the background color - in fact, using Stylebot scoped to localhost is better for me because I don't have to fix the css in every installation of jupyterlab in every Python environment.

Comment: I had the same issue. After changing the contrast on my monitor settings, the cell selections became visible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to open the jupyter-lab from the cmd, type this command :

```
jupyter notebook
```

it will open the same lab you can open via anaconda. then all of shortcuts will work as usual

Comment: No difference; still cannot select multiple adjacent cells. But thanks for trying.

Comment: did you open from cmd in virtual env?

Answer (score 0):

One trick that has worked for me was to enter into a cell by clicking into it (as in trying to edit the cell).
From here, hold Shift and click on the desired Cell number to multi-select on the left of the Cell outside the Cell box.